# ALSA-loop (aloop kernel module) send and receive hook points

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, alsa

I'm exploring some sample code of Aloop in the kernel-dir:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/drivers/aloop.c

1. I want to put there my own function which gets as parameter a pointer to a buffer of bytes and respectively number of bytes (whatever is coming from the userspace, let's say I'm using mpg321 for playing MP3) and my function then SENDS that data through UDP kernel socket implemented in the same aloop kernel module.
2. Let's say I've my own callback function which accepts again pointer to a buffer of bytes and number of bytes which bytes again are being RECEIVED through UDP kernel socket in the same aloop kernel module.

The problem is that I cannot see in the code of aloop.c where (and how) to  put my extra functionality - my function to send data and my callback which would provide the data to the userspace at the end...

Any recommendations and brainstorming on that are welcome!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the loopback driver. Read [Writing an ALSA driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html).

Comment: Actually the power of aloop example is that it is fully ALSA compliant - e.g. it supports multiple number of channels, sampling rates , etc. That's why I what to use it a basis for further development on top of it.
Actually I think I found my hook point (at least for sending out of the driver):

Comment: (line 432, function copy_play_buf()):    memcpy(dst + dst_off, src + src_off, size);

There I can put my sentto() function.

About the receiving I have to somehow attack the (dst + dst_off) pointer with real data received again through the UDP socket.

Comment: Have in mind that loopback_pos_update() function is being called by the loopback_pointer() which is actually the .pointer method of the driver and also from the loopback_timer_function().
Actually::
1. .pointer method is called whenever Userspace has been prepared new data and reordered the input ring buffer.
2. loopback_timer_function() simulates that the virtual HW (if it was a codec chip) consumed some data from the output buffer and wants new data.

The job of loopback_pos_update() function is to constantly balance the data between the two buffers.